# Nautilus Remote Connect shows only first directory

Tags: nautilus, ftp

I've connected to remote server with FTP via Nautilus' Remote Connect. The result only shows the first directory in the remote server, opening the first directory shows only the first directory in that directory... all the way until the last subdirectory - which is empty.

When I connect using the same credentials via FileZilla I am able to see the full directory listing.

Any ideas on why Nautilus would be having this problem?

Comment: Tried again the next morning and everything was fine. Not sure what if anything changed.

Comment: However, Bluefish and gEdit are showing only the first directory like Nautilus was yesterday.